# Как правильно вычислять географические расстояния в высоконагруженных сервисах?

Tags: java, архитектура, геометрия, геолокация

Есть сервис с пользователями и их местоположением. Допустим мне нужно получить всех пользователей в радиусе 500м от текущего пользователя.
И есть проблема, которая возникает при появлении большого количества пользователей. Для того что бы мне получить список пользователей в радиусе 500м мне нужно выполнить такие шаги: получить из БД всех пользователей, потом вычислить расстояние от текущего пользователя (тот который запросил этот список) до каждого пользователя, отфильтровать всех тех кто дальше чем 500м и вернуть оставшихся. От сюда вывод время которое нужно потратить на вычисления расстояния будет расти в арифметической прогрессии.
Я провел небольшое исследование (рост времени вычисления в зависимости от количества пользователей от 1 000 до 1 000 000, с шагом в 10 000).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как видно из графика 358 мс это достаточно много, учитывая то что все они могут одновременно это запрашивать.

Может это можно решить другим способом (функция вычисления расстояния наименьшая до не могу)?

Была идея сделать так: разбить всю поверхность Земли на квадраты. Потом определить в каком квадрате находится текущий пользователь и вычислять расстояние только до тех пользователей которые находятся только в этом квадрате.
Но тут возникает другая проблема: а если пользователи находятся в разных но смежных квадратах рядом с границей этих квадратов, то они уже не будут видеть друг друга?

**UPD:** База данных MySQL

Comment: Но тут возникает другая проблема: а если пользователи находятся в разных но смежных квадратах рядом с границей этих квадратов, то они уже не будут видеть друг друга? А что тебе мешает считать пользователей в смежных квадратах ? Т.е. текущий пользователь считает пользователей у себя в квардате + смежные, но остальные то отсеятся, те которые через квадрат. + Квадратная апроксимация расстояния.

Answer (score 2):

Если по каким то причинам ты не хочешь использовать postgis, то посмотри на такой алгоритм.

1. Найти всех в радиусе 500 м. Это можно апроксимировать квадратом. Т.е. фактически твое условие будет `where x between(my_location_x - 500, my_location_x +500) and y between(my_location_y - 500, my_location_y + 500)` При наличии индекса на x, y это log(n) быстрее ты врятли получишь.
2. При желании отфильтруй полученную первым пунктом выборку уже программно реальным кругом. Хотя я бы не стал. Дистанция до угла квадрата 1.41*r, разница в площадях квадрата и вписанного круга 1.27 раза. На меленьких дистанция смело можешь пренебречь.

Comment: А поможет ли postgis избежать фуллскана? Именно это убивает перформанс у автора. Перебирать всех пользователей, а тем более загружать и программно их фильтровать -- очень неэффективно, и автор пытается двигаться в сторону того, чтобы отсечь пользователей, которые заведомо не попадают в радиус.

Comment: @andreycha еще как. У постгиса есть индекс на геометрию.К примеру 
`SELECT * FROM geotable 
  WHERE ST_DWithin(geocolumn, 'POINT(1000 1000)', 500.0);`

Решает задачу автора. При наличии gist индекса на `geocolumn` это еще и работать будет с приемлемой скоростью.

Comment: Используется база данных MySQL

Comment: @VladimirAbramov выглядит круто. Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: А можно по-подробнее об этом:   При наличии индекса на x, y это log(n) .

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать не квадраты а метки, то есть разбить карту на сетку, и в местах пересечения линий установить метки (точки) расстояние между ними N метров. Найти ближайшую к пользователю метку, для каждого ползователя хранить ближайшую, а еще лучше для каждой метки хранить пользователей естественно у этой метки есть 8 соседних, пройдясь по этим меткам установить расстояние до пользователя остальных, принадлежащих этим меткам. Может и здесь есть подводные камни, как можно заметить, тут уменьшается исходная выборка
в случае если ползователь поменяет радиус, то нужно искасть соответственно подгоняя под расстояние N между метками, то есть искать уже не среди 8 соседних, а у соседей соседних (СС) и.т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема при большом количестве пользователей -- полный перебор. Будь то на уровне БД (`select * from Users where get_distance(Users.Location, CurrentLocation) < 500`), или программно (а тут еще и большие дополнительные затраты по памяти).

Избежать этого только некоторой сегментацией юзеров, которая позволит отсечь тех пользователей, который заведомо не попадают в радиус. Это позволит быстро (за счет индекса) получить на несколько порядков меньшую выборку (скажем, 10 тыс. вместо 10 млн.) и уже с ней работать. Вы правильно пытаетесь двигаться в этом направлении, пытаясь разбить пользователей на группы. Разбивать можно по-разному:

- Квадраты
- Страны (с использованием геокодирования)
- ???

Главный вопрос, на который нужно ответить, на мой взгляд: насколько актуальны д.б. данные, которые вы предоставляете пользователю? В зависимости от этого вы должны решить следующие вопросы:

- Своевременность обновления сегмента при обновлении
  местоположения пользователя
- Допустимо ли не показывать пользователей, которые попадают в
  радиус, но находятся в других сегментах? (В вашем варианте с квадратами этот вопрос можно решить, не только вычисляя текущий квадрат, но и проверяя расстояния до соседних квадратов.)